# Access DOM Element in Gutenberg Block on WP Admin Post Edit Screen

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

I'm developing a custom Gutenberg block called **Weekly Meetings Block** that was first created using the [@wordpress/create-block](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wordpress/create-block) npm package. For this block in the WP Admin, you can add options from a drop-down list (`select` tag) like choosing **Monday** from a **SELECT MEETING DAY OF WEEK** drop-down when a **Weekly Meeting Table Row Block** child block is added:
[image: child block]

When add this block on a localhost website on the live post the `.wp-block-create-block-meetings-table-block` DOM element is being accessed currently so that when I choose **Day of Week > Monday** for the `select` tag drop-down only the "Monday" meetings appear:
[image: filter live post]

However, in the WP Admin for the post when I try to select the `.wp-block-create-block-meetings-table-block` DOM element I see `NodeList(0)` when I used `console.log`:
[image: WP Admin JavaScript console log]

**In the WP Admin for my block how do I make code like `console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.wp-block-create-block-meetings-table-block'))` work so that I don't get an output of `NodeList(0)`?**

This probably involves using Vanilla JavaScript to access a virtual DOM created via React, but any help would be appreciated.

If you would like to test my code locally on your WP install see:

- This GitHub repo branch:
  https://github.com/Hollyw00d/weekly-meetings-list-block/tree/js-test-wp-admin
- And [lines 7 through 11 on this **utilities.js** file in the repo](https://github.com/Hollyw00d/weekly-meetings-list-block/blob/js-test-wp-admin/src/weekly-meetings-list/js/utilities.js#L7-L11)

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you need to select a DOM element? Generally you shouldn’t need to do this in React. Using logic in the render or something like a ref would be the React way to do it.

Comment: @JacobPeattie
I'd like to access the [__src/weekly-meetings-list/js/utilities.js__](https://github.com/Hollyw00d/weekly-meetings-list-block/blob/js-test-wp-admin/src/weekly-meetings-list/js/utilities.js) on both the WP Admin edit screen for a page/post AND the a live post/page which manipulates a DOM element so I won't have to refactor this code into React. This is my goal. 

And if I need to use `useRef` with React how would I do that?

Comment: Well refs wouldn’t help if that were your goal, because you’d still need separate React-only code.

Comment: @JacobPeattie
I found a path to a solution and will post an answer here, maybe next week. Thanks for your help anyway.